# Is scala able to infer type-constructor abstract type members?

Tags: scala, type-inference, type-constructor, scala-2.12

I am trying to extract abstract type members of implicit parameters (a la Shapeless), for example

```
trait F[T] { type Out }

object F {
  type Aux[T, out] = F[T] { type Out = out }
}

def glhf[t, out](implicit f: F.Aux[t, out]): out = ???
```

This works like a charm for any kind of extraction (even complicated cross-implicit type variables).

However, when the abstract type member is a type constructor and not a simple type, the compiler fails to do unify the type variable at the invocation point.

I have made a small test case in which there is a weird compilation error. The compiler error does not make much sense itself, so I am wondering whether this is a compiler bug? See the code sample for the error message details.

Compiled with `scala-2.12.4`, `-Xlog-implicits` for the extra messages, and even `-Ypartial-unification` in case that would be the problem.

`incubator/Main.scala`:

```
package incubator

object wat {

  /**
   * A "type class", "implicit evidence" type, etc...
   *
   * @tparam t just for looks, and facilitate
   *  the implicit resolution scenario
   */
  trait fo[t] {
    /**
     * An abstract type member THAT IS A TYPE CONSTRUCTOR
     */
    type f[_]
  }

  //
  // Types that will be used for `fo`'s abstract type `f[_]`
  //
  trait F1[t]
  trait F2[t]
  //
  // Couple of case for type class `fo`
  //
  trait loo
  implicit object loo extends loo with fo[loo] {
    type f[t] = F1[t]
  }
  //
  trait poo
  implicit object poo extends poo with fo[poo] {
    type f[t] = F2[t]
  }

  // Double checking, this compiles
  val w0 = implicitly[ fo[loo] ]
  val w1 = implicitly[ fo[poo] ]

  /**
   * *** PROBLEM HERE ***
   * 
   * A method call, in which the abstract TYPE CONSTRUCTOR type member
   * needs to be inferred by the compiler.
   *
   * This fails to be implicitly resolved, because the compiler
   * fails to instantiate the type parameters, (probably) because
   * it is unable to infer abstract type `f`. See further below
   * for the failed invocation.
   *
   */
  def fu0[t, in[_]](t: t)(
    implicit
    fo: fo[t] { type f[a] = in[a] }
  ): String = s"Hi $t: $fo"

  // These will work fine, since we explicitly set type param `in`
  val w2 = fu0[loo, F1](loo: loo)
  val w3 = fu0[poo, F2](poo: poo)

  // *** PROBLEM HERE ***
  // The following fails to compile
  val w4 = fu0(loo: loo) // type ascription for test simplification
  val w5 = fu0(poo: poo) // type ascription for test simplification

  //
  // Error message:
  //
  // (notice the "type f has one type parameter, but type in has one"
  //  part of the error)
  //
  // [info] .../incubator/Main.scala:64:15: poo is not a valid implicit value for incubator.wat.fo[incubator.wat.poo]{type f[a] = in[a]} because:
  // [info] type parameters weren't correctly instantiated outside of the implicit tree: inferred kinds of the type arguments (incubator.wat.poo.f[t]) do not conform to the expected kinds of the type parameters (type in).
  // [info] incubator.wat.poo.f[t]'s type parameters do not match type in's expected parameters:
  // [info] type f has one type parameter, but type in has one
  // [info]   val w5 = fu0(poo: poo) // type ascription for test simplification
  // [info]               ^
  // [info] .../incubator/Main.scala:64:15: incubator.this.wat.poo is not a valid implicit value for incubator.wat.fo[incubator.wat.poo]{type f[a] = in[a]} because:
  // [info] type parameters weren't correctly instantiated outside of the implicit tree: inferred kinds of the type arguments (incubator.wat.poo.f[t]) do not conform to the expected kinds of the type parameters (type in).
  // [info] incubator.wat.poo.f[t]'s type parameters do not match type in's expected parameters:
  // [info] type f has one type parameter, but type in has one
  // [info]   val w5 = fu0(poo: poo) // type ascription for test simplification
  // [info]               ^
  // [error] .../incubator/Main.scala:64:15: could not find implicit value for parameter fo: incubator.wat.fo[incubator.wat.poo]{type f[a] = in[a]}
  // [error]   val w5 = fu0(poo: poo) // type ascription for test simplification
  // [error]               ^
  // [error] two errors found
  // [error] (compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
  // [error] Total time: 1 s, completed Oct 22, 2017 4:48:35 PM
  //

}
```

Answer (score 0):

By using following definition in `fu0` you basically remaking `fo` so the compiler doesn't know exactly what is going on.

```
implicit
fo: fo[t] { type f[a] = in[a] }
```

You already defined `fo` and by using that static trait you won't have to use explicit typing.

```
def fu0[t, in[_]]
    (t: t)
    (implicit fo: fo[t] ): String = s"Hi $t: $fo"
```

It works on the provoded example but I would assume that in your real case the issue lies deeper in nested types. If my assessment is accurate please provide more specific test case so we could look into it. It's quite an interesting topic.

**Reproduction**

Clean setup with `scalaVersion := "2.12.4"`

```
package io.sosc

object Main {

    trait fo[t] {

        type f[_]
    }

    trait F1[t]
    trait F2[t]

    trait loo

    implicit object loo extends loo with fo[loo] {
        type f[t] = F1[t]
    }

    trait poo

    implicit object poo extends poo with fo[poo] {
        type f[t] = F2[t]
    }

    def fu0[t, in[_]]
        (t: t)
        (implicit fo: fo[t] ): String = s"Hi $t: $fo"


    def main( args: Array[ String ] ): Unit = {



        val w0 = implicitly[ fo[loo] ]
        val w1 = implicitly[ fo[poo] ]

        val w2 = fu0[loo, F1](loo: loo)
        val w3 = fu0[poo, F2](poo: poo)

        println( w2 )
        println( w3 )

        val w4 = fu0(loo: loo)
        val w5 = fu0(poo: poo)

        println( w4 )
        println( w5 )
    }
}
```

Result:

```
Hi io.sosc.Main$loo$@465ba3d7: io.sosc.Main$loo$@465ba3d7
Hi io.sosc.Main$poo$@675b0a69: io.sosc.Main$poo$@675b0a69
Hi io.sosc.Main$loo$@465ba3d7: io.sosc.Main$loo$@465ba3d7
Hi io.sosc.Main$poo$@675b0a69: io.sosc.Main$poo$@675b0a69
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Dennis, but as you meniton the point is that type parameter `in[_]` is reused in the method's signature. Your solution simply removes the type variable from the signature. The question needs clarification to specify this use case. Thanks again.

Comment: Tag me in the comment when you make comprehensive test case :)